# Difference between php bin/magento and bin/magento

Tags: magento2, command-line

In Magento when we run any command we use 'php bin/magento' and sometimes it runs also with 'bin/magento'

So can any one explain what is the actual difference in these commands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference between these two command.

```
php bin/magento
```

**php bin/magento** command you are using php global variable to run command. for example if you are not set the global variable then you can give path of php like  /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento to run the magento command.

```
bin/magento
```

**bin/magento** command will find the golbal php variable and use that,

Note: in both cases it will use the **php** variable

Answer (score 2):

Its same things :)

But generaly adding PHP you can choose to add command line option
see [PHP features commandline options](http://php.net/manual/fr/features.commandline.options.php)

```
php -c /custom/directory/custom-file.ini bin/magento [command]
```

By omitting it ... it is the default version of the system that is used

It is better to launch the magento binary with the same version as the one used with the WEB server, do not forget that in command line we are in CLI

you can see something like this on debian... depending of your compilation and version

```
#php -v
PHP 7.1.20-1+0~20180725103315.2+stretch~1.gbpd5b650 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2018 10:33:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.20-1+0~20180725103315.2+stretch~1.gbpd5b650, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 0):

The `php bin/magento` command is the recommended way to execute Magento CLI commands, as it allows you to specify the PHP version you want to use.

For example:

- To run the command using PHP 7.4: `php7.4 bin/magento c:f`
- To run the command using PHP 8.1: `php8.1 bin/magento c:f`

By prefixing the `bin/magento` command with `php` followed by the desired PHP version, you ensure that the command is executed using the specified PHP version. This is particularly useful when you have multiple PHP versions installed on your system and need to specify the one compatible with your Magento installation.